# can't create multiple contacts and emails in django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a contact that contains users and users can have multiple phone numbers and contact numbers. I can't find where the problem is? When I try to migrate is shows:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
   Select an option:

**models.py code:**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
status = models.BooleanField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['full_name']

class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    user_emails = models.ForeignKey(
        Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='emails', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class PhoneNum(models.Model):
    contact_num = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_contacts = models.ForeignKey(
        Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="contact_numbers", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_num
```

**serializers.py code:**

```
from django.db.models import fields
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Contact, Email, PhoneNum

class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'


class MultipleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    emails = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    contacts = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Email, PhoneNum
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py code:**

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing contacts.
"""
queryset = Contact.objects.all()
serializer_class = ContactSerializer
```

Help to get this please.

Comment: There is no problem. Seems you are applying migration on database which isn't empty, so Django is asking to provide default value for records which already exist.

Comment: There is no problem. You added an extra field and now Django needs to know what value to fill in in that column for the records that already exist.

Comment: @kamran890: lol, the same comment within less than ~6 seconds :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Amazing coincidence!